# Creating a boarder around patterned text

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have put a pattern into my text and now I am wanting to create a boarder around each individual letter. Can someone please tell me a easy way to do this in illustrator?

Thanks Bec. :)

Answer (score 1):

Letter borders are called stroke, you just have to turn it on, pick a color and thickness.

The stroke can also contain patterns.

To apply different stroke outlines to different letters you need to separate the letters into different text boxes or flatten them and ungroup, then apply stroke to each letter.